# server communication

Tags: sockets

We have a Websphere app server with one cluster containing 2 servers. Each server contains our webapp. Each webapp/server talks to an single NCipher server though sockets. The NCipher server is listening for communications from each webapp/server on a common port.
If we reboot each of the Websphere servers in the cluster individually then we find that one connects straightaway but the other takes a variable amount of reboots before it connects. What I find confusing is why one connects immediately but the other doesn't.

What I have noticed is that connections are not being closed in the webapp. Not sure what impact this may have given that one of the servers is connecting fine once rebooted and the other doesn't.

Even though not closed I guess the connections do timeout, although closing them is definitely the correct thing to do.

Would anybody have any idea as to why this may be occuring ?